# Edit mode keeps switching from edge / Face mode to Vertex mode without me doing so

Tags: edit-mode

So I have recently switched from 3ds Max to Blender and I am still figuring out the layout of things. I believe I have either changed a setting or turned on a feature that, while in edit mode, will automatically switch to Vertex mode when I click to edit my object, even when not wanting it to do so. Shift-clicking works to stay in a selected edit tool, but I was able to just select using left-click as long as I was in the correct edit mode for what I wanted to do. I was just wondering if anyone might know what I have done. I do have a Reddit post that can better show what I mean since I can't upload a video here. Sorry for the mess about with the link to another location but I don't think images would help understand the problem. thanks for any sort of help.

P.S. Sorry for not double-checking that these things went through.

Link to video:https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/18y5qxg/edit_mode_keeps_switching_from_edge_face_mode_to/

[image]

Comment: Where is the link to Reddit post?

Comment: Posting a still image of your Blender window might give us a clue as to what's happening even without a link to your Reddit post. Use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu and then follow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Apologies for not double-checking the post to make sure the link went through.

Answer (score 1):

Blender allows you to filter elements for selection in Edit Mode.

In particular:

[image]

These boxes can be shift-clicked to include or exclude vertices, edges, faces as candidate selection targets.

The same logic applies to the standard key-mapping: <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd> can also be toggled with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, (barring the exclusion of all targets).

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, thanks for pointing that out. Might have to just spend a session playing with all the tools rather than just jumping straight into projects again.

Comment: @Bewalk hehe.. that would take for ever.. maybe better to let the UI grow on you, during real work. Blender is full of Easter eggs, and you can be confident that they are considered; most of them make sense.  The only real tip I would suggest for accelerating discovery  is: keep an eye on the info bar at the bottom of the screen showing you the options, when you use any tool. I do miss some things, but I came away from 3DS because I got tired of hunting through forests of buttons. I'd rather have a chisel, and know how to use it, than an automated mortising machine.